# Trouble to create new subscription

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am getting trouble to creating new  subscription in the Local publication.

I was able to create the Local publication at the Replication

However, after I created sub subscription and I just right clicked the subscription and clicked "View synchronization state "

It is displaying only this message

> The concurrent snapshot for publication 'Publisher_team7' is not available because it has not been fully generated or the Log Reader
>   Agent is not running to activate it. If generation of the concurrent
>   snapshot was interrupted, the Snapshot Agent for the

I am not really sure the solution of this problem.

I also tried to delete Local publications and start again but i can not delete .

I can only see this error message

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission. Changed database context to 'TV_Data'. (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the replication monitor.  You should be able to look at each of the log reader, snapshot, and distribution agent's status and get specific status for each of them.  Troubleshoot them in the order above as that's how data flows from publisher to distributor to subscriber.  A lot can go wrong with replication, so I'll need to know more before troubleshooting further.